# Docker Windows Bind Mount not Copying and Refreshing Data

Tags: docker

I'm using Docker on Windows. Versions are engine: 20.10.14, desktop: 4.7.0. In my current director, I have a DockerFile (unimportant for now) and an index.html file.
[image]

I created an nginx docker container with a bind mount to copy these files into the container: `docker container run -d --name nginx_cust -p 80:80 -v %cd%:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx`.

When I access `localhost:80`, I don't see my index.html file reflected, and when I enter the running container with bash `docker container exec -it nginx_cust bash` and check the mounted directory, it's empty:
[image]
Inspecting the container, I see that the bind mount does look correct,
[image]
and I don't see anything in the container log about this. Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: One thing I notice is that your mount info says that you mount to /USR/SHARE/NGINX/HTML. Since Linux is case sensitive with regard to filenames, that might cause what you're seeing. If you exec into the container, is there a /USR (upper case) directory?

Comment: Good observation, but there is no /USR directory in the container FS.

Comment: OK. 2 things you can try: 1) drop 'container' from your commands, so it's just `docker run`. I think it might be irrelevant, but 'docker run' and 'docker container run' have different man pages 2) use the Windows command line rather than Cmder

Comment: Tried those  - no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of playing around, I realized that this got fixed when I moved the input files to different directory - one that was less-deeply nested. I strongly suspect there was some long filename constraint being violated silently.